# Problemas con Dateformat en Android Studio

Tags: android, string, date, studio

Debido a mi inexperiencia no encuentro el motivo del por qué al parsear fechaString lo guarda con dia, mes, año, hora, minutos y segundos! (Sólo quiero recuperar la fecha, sin hora ni minutos ni segundos)

Hice un calendario que al seleccionar una fecha ya lo deja con un String formato DD/MM/AAAA, la idea es parsearlo a Date para guardarlo en el objeto.

```
onDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;
            String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            txtFechaEmpollado.setText(date);
        }
    };

//Esto pertenece a otra parte del código más abajo, dentro de un setOnClickListener
 String fechaString = txtFechaEmpollado.getText().toString();
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

                Date fechaEmpollado = dateFormat.parse(fechaString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Al obtener los valores `day`, `month`, `year` directamente del `DatePickerDialog` puedes realizar la conversión:

```
onDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;
            String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            txtFechaEmpollado.setText(date);

            /*------------------------*/
            try{    
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            calendar.set(year, month, day);

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String formatedDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());

             //Convierte a objeto Date
             Date date = sdf.parse(formatedDate);

             } catch (ParseException e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "formateDateFromstring(): " + e.getMessage());
             }

             /*------------------------*/
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tomarte la molestia y responder mi posteo,
la última línea: Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(formatedDate);

Me tira error en la parte del parse D:

Comment: Hola,, seguramente necesitas "atrapar" el error ParseException por si ocurre, actualice la respuesta. @PSM